# How to create horizontal columns in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a Beamer presentation, and I want a slide that has the following format:

> figure -> some itemization -> figure

So on the far left I want to have an image, then some itemization next to the figure, and then on the far right another figure. So itemization is between two figures. But, I want to have three of these in one slide, one under the other. So I want to have three horizontal column, each having the above format.

I know the `\begin{column}` thing, but it creates vertical columns. I need horizontal ones. Any idea how to achieve this? Currently, I have just just this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MD}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pkc}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{skc}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{protocols}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It just loads the three figures one under the other correctly, but they are not in the far left of course, but in the middle. And I don't know how to achieve this horizontal columns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this the layout you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MD}

\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \item item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \item item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \item item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is more or less what I want, and I thought about it also. But in this setting there is too much blank space between the columns like between the first image and the itemize, or itemize and the second image. What I want is to have minimum possible blank space between them, so that images can be bigger.

Comment: @typos You can easily make the images bigger, they are just 70% of the textwidth and make the column of the items smaller. But with bigger images, I had the problem that 3 of them did not fit below each other.

Comment: Thanks, I actually adapted your solution to my needs. :)